# Finding an element in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the path to the `value = 1260` element without knowing which staircase of the array it is on.
If there are several such elements, the first.
That's what I did, but here it sends an array in which this element (and I need a path to this element)

```
function searchA($array, $nsearch) {
foreach ($array as $el) {
    if(in_array($nsearch, $el)){
        print_r($el);
    } else{
        searchA($el);
        }
}
```

This array= [array](https://pastebin.com/zbp92ZAV)

**My require:**

Create a function to find an element in an array

**Sample:**

```
2018-02, will return [Stats][0][Season]
```

**Sample functions look like:**

```
function searchA($array, $nsearch)
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If not maybe you should update the question or tell what is not working for an answer. If any of the answers helped you, you should mark it as the answer

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what you have already tried maybe you can try this:

```
$key = array_search( $valueYouLookFor, array_column( $array, $keyName ) );
```

Usage:

```
$key = array_search( '2018-02', array_column( $array, 'date' ) );
```

This will only give you the key, from there you can get other values.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is recursive search, change output to suit your needs:

```
<?php

function array_search_path_recursive(array $haystack, $needle)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_search_path_recursive($value, $needle);

            if ($result !== false) {
                return $key . '.' . $result;
            }

        } elseif ($value === $needle) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo array_search_path_recursive([['foo' => ['bar' => 'baz']]], 'baz');
# => 0.foo.bar
```